# When the attribute value can remain unquoted in HTML5

Tags: html, attributes

When the attribute value can remain unquoted in HTML5?

HTML4.01 was a SGML application. So in HTML4 quotes can be omitted if the only characters used in the value are ones currently declared as name characters: alphanumeric character, full stop, -, :, _.

Well, from the W3C working draft (13 January 2011):

> The attribute value can remain
>   unquoted if it doesn't contain spaces
>   or any of " ' ` = < or >.

But if I put in the attribute value any other character than alphanumeric character, full stop, -, :, _ and remain it unquoted validator.w3.org doesn't validate my html document as valid HTML5 document.

So the question is still open. Is it a mistake of HTML5 working draft or is it a mistake on validate.w3.org?

Comment: [This article on unquoted attribute values in HTML and CSS](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/unquoted-attribute-values) will answer your question. There’s also a tool: http://mothereff.in/unquoted-attributes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the working draft is fine and the validator is working correctly.

Try this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<title>test</title>
<div class=%test$></div>
```

at http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input

The validator is happy with both the % and $ characters. So what exactly are you testing?

Comment: Ok this is not reproduced anymore. But two weeks ago this was reproduced. I should have tested again before publish this question yesterday.  So the question is closed. Thanks

Comment: Although $ should be escaped in most cases too

Comment: `%test$` is indeed a valid unquoted attribute value in HTML. However, it isn’t in CSS: http://mothereffingunquotedattributes.com/#%25test%24

Answer (score 1):

[This article on unquoted attribute values in HTML and CSS](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/unquoted-attribute-values) will answer your question. There’s also a tool: http://mothereff.in/unquoted-attributes

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are sticking in the xmlns attribute to your html element, rendering your document as XHTML 5 (the XML serialization of HTML 5), using unquoted values with appropriate characters validates as proper HTML 5.