# Double quotes within php script echo

Tags: javascript, php, syntax, echo

I have a line of php code that looks like this:

```
echo "<script>$('#edit_errors').html('<h3><em>Please Correct Errors Before Proceeding</em></h3>')</script>";
```

I would like to know how to add a font color to the text correctly.
If I do this:

```
echo "<script>$('#edit_errors').html('<h3><em><font color="red">Please Correct Errors Before Proceeding</font></em></h3>')</script>";
```

The word "red" is in black text and the compiler throws an error.

If I use single quotes around red, then the text does not show up at all.

Any help would be great.
Thanks

Answer (score 66, accepted):

You need to escape `"`, so it won't be interpreted as end of string. Use `\` to escape it:

```
echo "<script>$('#edit_errors').html('<h3><em><font color=\"red\">Please Correct Errors Before Proceeding</font></em></h3>')</script>";
```

Read more: [strings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) and [escape sequences](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php)

Answer (score 13):

use a [HEREDOC](http://php.net/heredoc), which eliminates any need to swap quote types and/or escape them:

```
echo <<<EOL
<script>$('#edit_errors').html('<h3><em><font color="red">Please Correct Errors Before Proceeding</font></em></h3>')</script>
EOL;
```

Answer (score 4):

Just escape your quotes:

```
echo "<script>$('#edit_errors').html('<h3><em><font color=\"red\">Please Correct Errors Before Proceeding</font></em></h3>')</script>";
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to escape the quotes in the string by adding a backslash `\` before `"`.

Like:

```
"<font color=\"red\">"
```

Comment: how to write < or > characters. Since writing them changes to &lt; and &gt; respectively :(

Answer (score 2):

if you need to access your variables for an echo statement within your quotes put your variable inside curly brackets

```
echo "i need to open my lock with its: {$array['key']}";
```

Comment: This is not what OP asked.

Answer (score 1):

You can just forgo the quotes for alphanumeric attributes:

```
echo "<font color=red> XHTML is not a thing anymore. </font>";
echo "<div class=editorial-note> There, I said it. </div>";
```

Is perfectly valid in HTML, and though still shunned, absolutely en vogue since HTML5.

**CAVEATS**

- It's only valid for mostly alphanumeric and dash combinations.
- Never ever do this with user input appended to attributes (those need quoting and [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars) or some whitelisting).
- See also: [When the attribute value can remain unquoted in HTML5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5445385/when-the-attribute-value-can-remain-unquoted-in-html5)
- In other news: `<font>` specifically is somewhat outdated however.