# Include larger block of formatting with Heredoc EOL in PHP

Tags: php

I have a series of echo statements that are going to be a pain as I need to add more formatting.  [I found an example of HEREDOC here that looked pretty good](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11036420/double-quotes-within-php-script-echo).

I want to replace these series of echo statements but it is not working.

Existing code:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {

  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['EmpFirstName'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['EmpLastName'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</table>";
```

New attempt (not working)

```
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
      {

      echo <<<EOL 
       <tr>
         <td>" . $row['EmpFirstName'] . "</td>
         <td>" . $row['EmpLastName'] . "</td>
      </tr>
      }
    </table>
      EOL;
```

Comment: Sidenote: Your posted code contains spaces before `EOL;` there must not be any before it. (Most probably the (or a) cause, if that's the  actual code you're using).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're opening the HEREDOC inside the `while` loop, but not closing it until after the loop. And you don't need to open and close quotes to include the variables. You need to do it this way:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo <<<EOL 
       <tr>
           <td>{$row['EmpFirstName']}</td>
           <td>{$row['EmpLastName']}</td>
       </tr>
EOL;
}
echo "</table>";
```

Note the lack of spaces before `EOL`, as noted by Fred and FreshPrince.

Comment: I'm getting a syntax error starting on this line still?     echo <<<EOL

Comment: It's not that line that's the problem, see my updated answer. You need the curly braces (`{}`) around the array variables (or you can remove the single quotes around the keys, but I prefer to use the braces).

Comment: I'm still getting the syntax error...screenshot here:  https://www.dropbox.com/s/j30qw7g53ebta1i/syntax.jpg

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with that code and it works fine when I try it - do you get an error when actually viewing the page, or just in your editor?