# print to screen a website.

Tags: php, html

I know this is wrong but I am not sure how. Can someone tell me nicely what is wrong with it?

```
print "<a href="https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/desktop/" target='_blank' class='gemma' style='position: fixed; bottom: 0; right: 0; text-align:right; width:100%; padding:20px;'>Works best in Chrome web browser</a>";
```

Comment: use iframe for this

Comment: what is your question ?

Comment: Can anyone tell me why I am getting an error with this single line of code?

Comment: what is iframe?

Comment: print "<a href='https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/desktop/' target='_blank' class='gemma' style='position: fixed; bottom: 0; right: 0; text-align:right; width:100%; padding:20px;'>Works best in Chrome web browser</a>";

Comment: You need to escape the double quotes in your string.

Comment: with iframes you can include other pages like facebook.com or google.com into your site

Comment: what are you trying to do ? just print it on a white background page?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Double quotes within php script echo](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11036420/double-quotes-within-php-script-echo)

Comment: I KNEW I had a problem right after the address. I just didn't know how to fix it.

Comment: Thanks for the downvote and the answer. I appreciated the latter more though.

Comment: For future reference, the downvotes are probably because you didn't say what was wrong with it. You need to also include in your question any exception you are getting or what your expected and actual output is.

Comment: There wasn't a general error. I just knew by looking at the code in the progammer's notepad that there was an error. But how do I say "gee this code is green and it should be blue?" And you all will completely understand what I am trying to say right? The best that I could give you was that there was a problem with that line of code. I knew it had to be after the double quotes because the code went green and it should go black.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way for this would be to write the HTML exactly as normal, with double quotes, and just wrap the string in single quotes. You should also use `echo`, not `print`:

```
echo '<a href="https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/desktop/" target="_blank" class="gemma" style="position: fixed; bottom: 0; right: 0; text-align:right; width:100%; padding:20px;">Works best in Chrome web browser</a>';
```

Comment: What is the difference between echo and print?

Comment: There are slight differences, among them, echo is marginally faster than print(). You'll find more info here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7094118/reference-comparing-phps-print-and-echo

Comment: so it's kinda like using if else statements or choosing to use case statements?

Comment: Sort of, yes, although you'd normally use `echo` for outputting content to the browser/UI - print is rarely used, and as stated, mostly for evaluating functions / have a specific return value.

Comment: Print is used rampantly in this code so I will continue with it. I see no real need to change it now.

Comment: By all means, but that might be an indication that the code isn't very good, and/or in desperate need of updating. Having the `target="_blank"` suggests the same, so... proceed with caution.

Comment: try in desperate need of updating. I am working on that. When I start the real serious part of updating print will leave and echo will come out and play.