# How to work with double quotes and single quotes in php

Tags: php, echo

I just wonder how people work with double and single quotes. I have a code where i got a little problem.

If i for example got this code:

```
<img src="img_fjords.jpg" onclick="document.getElementById('someID').style.display='block'" class="w3-hover-opacity">
```

Now i got no problem, but if im going to put this inside a `echo ""` then i start getting problems, so i changed all the double quotes to single quotes and used double quotes for the echo, but still it will not accept it, i think i got to many single quotes now. and i think i need to do something different with "someID"?

echo code:

```
echo "<img src='img_fjords.jpg' onclick='document.getElementById('someID').style.display='block'' class='w3-hover-opacity'";
```

Comment: Start reading please http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to escape double quotes if your string is put in double quotes by using backslash `\` character. Here is an example:

```
echo "String with \"double quotes\"";
```

So in your case it will be:

```
echo "<img src=\"img_fjords.jpg\" onclick=\"document.getElementById('someID').style.display='block'\" class=\"w3-hover-opacity\"";
```

Ref: [Double quotes within php script echo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11036433/2811746)

Answer (score 2):

You can escape the quotes where needed (using backslashes before the quote signs):

```
echo "<img src='img_fjords.jpg' onclick='document.getElementById(\"someID\").style.display=\"block\"' class='w3-hover-opacity'";
```