# how to give quotes in php for html attributes

Tags: php, html

```html
echo "<tr onclick='window.location=("www.google.com")'>
      <td>something</td>
      <td>something</td>
    </tr>"
```

i have written code like this but it is not working.i dont know where to put single quotes and double qoutes.
I dont know how to write onclick for  in php
please suggest me

Comment: `echo "<tr onclick=\"window.location=(\"www.google.com\")\"'>";`

Comment: You should read the difference between double or single quotes [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3446286/6140684)

Comment: @Masivuye That produces invalid HTML syntax.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Double quotes within php script echo](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11036420/double-quotes-within-php-script-echo)

Comment: most easy way is ?> <tr onclick='window.location=("<? echo 'www.google.com'; ?>")'>
      <td>something</td>
      <td>something</td>
    </tr> <?php

Comment: @Masivuye Cokile it is not working

Comment: dont echo out more then you need to it just leads to mistakes and syntax errors if you not sure how to use ' and " quotes , ps to echo html it is better to echo ' your html " also html " ' because html uses "

Comment: thanks @ Gert really it is an easiest way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Avoid using `echo` for HTML. Leave PHP mode and go into output mode.

Avoid using nested literal values. Write each language as a separate variable, use suitable escaping functions to add whatever quotes you need and then put them together.

By keeping everything as separate layers and dealing with them one at a time, and by using functions instead of trying to write your escapes manually, you make things much easier to maintain.

```
$url = "http://www.google.com";
$js_string_literal_url = json_encode($url);
$js = "window.location = $js_string_literal_url";
$html_safe_js = htmlspecialchars($js);

?>
<tr onclick="<?php echo $html_safe_js; ?>">
  <td>something</td>
  <td>something</td>
</tr>
```

---

That said, you should also avoid:

- Features which depend entirely on JS
- `onclick` attributes

Write HTML that works, and then enhance with JS.

If you want to link somewhere: use a link:

```
<tr>
  <td><a href="http://www.google.com">something</a></td>
  <td>something</td>
</tr>
```

If you want to make that link work (using JS) for the whole table row, bind an event listener that looks for clicks, and then find the first link in the row that was clicked on.

```
document.querySelector("table").addEventListener(follow_link_in_row);
function follow_link_in_row(event) {
    var table_row = event.target;
    while (table_row && table_row.tagName.toLowerCase() !== "tr") {
        table_row = table_row.parentNode;
    }
    if (!table_row) { return; }
    var link = table_row.querySelector("a[href]");
    var url = link.href;
    window.location = url;
}
```