# Make a JavaScript alert code without using any double quotes

Tags: javascript, php, html, dom-events, alert

This code is a part my webpage:

```
<span onclick=alert('Name:$commenter_name <br>Email:$commenter_email <br> Rate:$commenter_rate <br>Comment time:$currentdate <br>Comment:$commenter_comment')>$commenter_name:$commenter_comment
    <span class='post_time'>$currentdate</span>
</span>
```

The JavaScript alert is not working.

I want to make this code working, **without using any double quotes**.

Here's my whole PHP code:

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['post'])){    
        $commenter_name = $_POST["commenter_name"];
        $commenter_email = $_POST["commenter_email"];
        $commenter_rate = $_POST["commenter_rate"];
        $commenter_comment = $_POST["commenter_comment"];
        $currentdate = date('d F Y');
        $fianl = "Name:$commenter_name <br>Email:$commenter_email <br> Rate:$commenter_rate <br>Comment time:$currentdate<br>Comment:$commenter_comment";
        $filename = getcwd() . "/Comma comments.php"; 
        $line_i_am_looking_for = 2; 
        $lines = file( $filename , FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES ); 
        $lines[$line_i_am_looking_for] =    "
        <tr>
            <td>
                 <span onclick=alert('$fianl')>$commenter_name$commenter_comment
                      <span class='post_time'> $currentdate </span>
                 </span><hr><br>
           </td>
        </tr>";
       file_put_contents( $filename , implode( "\n", $lines ) );
    }
?>
```

Please help

Comment: If you thing, this question is inappropriate, then please don't dowvote or put this question on hold. Just tell me to delete it.

Comment: Else please answer quickly

Comment: HTML attributes need quotes `<span onclick="alert('foo')">content</span>`, I also don't think html breaks work in an alert box, you might have to use `\n`. Why can't you use double quotes?

Comment: It seems impossible by the standard, however, try to hack your browser; it **might** be possible.

Comment: @JimL: no, html5 doesn't need quotes around attribute values, unless the value contain a quote, space, equal, or lt...

Comment: @dandavis that a new info

Comment: What happens if I add JavaScript inside event attributes? Will it work without double quotes?

Comment: `<span onclick=setTimeout(function(){alert(123)},500)> ;) </span>`

Comment: @dandavis will this work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Double quotes within php script echo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11036420/double-quotes-within-php-script-echo)

Answer (score 1):

I've made the answer myself.
Here's the code:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['post'])){

        $commenter_name = $_POST["commenter_name"];
        $commenter_email = $_POST["commenter_email"];
        $commenter_rate = $_POST["commenter_rate"];
        $commenter_comment = $_POST["commenter_comment"];
        $currentdate = date('d F Y');
        $fianl = "Name\:$commenter_name \\n Email\:$commenter_email \\n Rate\:$commenter_rate \\n Comment time\:$currentdate \\n Comment\:$commenter_comment";
$filename = getcwd() . "/Comma comments.php"; 
$line_i_am_looking_for = 2; 
$lines = file( $filename , FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES ); 
$lines[$line_i_am_looking_for] =    "
<tr>
 <td colspan='2'>
 <span onclick=\"alert('$fianl')\">$commenter_name$commenter_comment <span class='post_time'> $currentdate </span></span><hr>
<br>
</td></tr>";
file_put_contents( $filename , implode( "\n", $lines ) );
}
?>
```

`\"` tells the PHP script to ignore the double quotes. `\\n` tells the PHP script to ignore `\n`.
 That's all.

Comment: I got the informations from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11036420/double-quotes-within-php-script-echo