# How to echo a href when using a variable from mysqli

Tags: php, echo, href

I have a variable retrieved from a mysqli database called eBayURL.
I am attempting to assign the variable to a button.

However I get an error when using

```
echo "<a target='"_blank"' href='".$row['eBayURL']."' class="btn btn-outlined btn-primary btn-md">Click Here <br> To Book Now </a></li>'";
```

I have also tried with { but also seems to fail.
What is the correct syntax please?

Comment: echo "<a target='_blank' href='".$row['eBayURL']."' class='btn btn-outlined btn-primary btn-md'>Click Here <br> To Book Now </a></li>";

Comment: Your code contains several parse errors concerning quotes. You need to revisit how quotes and, within them, escaping quotes, works.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP parse/syntax errors; and how to solve them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050071/php-parse-syntax-errors-and-how-to-solve-them)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Double quotes within php script echo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11036420/double-quotes-within-php-script-echo)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an incorrect mix of [single and double quotes](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php).

Try the following instead:

```
echo '<a target="_blank" href="'.$row['eBayURL'].'" class="btn btn-outlined btn-primary btn-md">Click Here <br> To Book Now </a></li>';
```

Or you can use:

```
echo "<a target=\"_blank\" href=\"".$row['eBayURL']."\" class=\"btn btn-outlined btn-primary btn-md\">Click Here <br> To Book Now </a></li>";
```

You could get crazy and use [`printf()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.printf.php) as well if you like:

```
$format = '<a target="_blank" href="%s" class="btn btn-outlined btn-primary btn-md">Click Here <br> To Book Now </a></li>';
printf($format,$row['eBayURL']);
```

If that fails, please check the value of `$row['eBayURL']` like so:

```
var_dump($row['eBayURL']);
```

Answer (score 0):

You mixed double quote and single quote in your `anchor` tag, try this -

```
echo "<a target='_blank' href='".$row['eBayURL']."' class='btn btn-outlined btn-primary btn-md'>Click Here <br> To Book Now </a></li>";
```

Comment: Thank you so much.  Much appreciated.

Comment: My pleasure :). If my answer helps you please upvote it. @bitzer